# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre declarar inline y a través de una variable?

Tags: javascript

He comenzado a aprender JS y en un ejercicio de modificación de elementos del DOM, encuentro las siguientes dos maneras de realizar la misma función, aunque aún no entiendo en que situaciones aplicar una u otra y cuál es el nombre de cada instrucción.

A

```
document.querySelector('.contenido h1').textContent = "Nuevo heading";
```

B

```
const nHeading = 'Nuevo heading'; 
document.querySelector('.contenido h1').textContent = nHeading;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Básicamente las 2 opciones hacen lo mismo, pero cuando empieces a recibir datos de origenes externos, ya sea otro archivo, una llamada o simplemente un array u objeto recorrido por ejemplo, el dato que utilizarías sería variable, entonces aplicarías la opción B, la opción A está perfecto si es un string específico estático que deseas agregar a ese elemento..

Supongamos que consultamos a una base de datos y volcamos el nombre recibido en una variable  ej:

```
const nombrePersona = result.nombre
```

Ese valor cambiaría dependiendo a que persona hagamos la consulta.
Entonces sin importar cual sea el dato recibido, al hacer:

```
document.querySelector('.contenido h1').textContent = nombrePersona;
```

Se agregaría en ese campo el nombre correspondiente a la persona consultada en la DB, es decir, este valor sería dinámico.

Al final en general vas a trabajar siempre con variables para mostrar sus valores.

En resumen, la opción B se utiliza cuando no sabes que dato recibirás, es decir este es variable.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo entendi perfecto, la respuesta era más sencilla de lo que yo estaba especulando.

Comment: A las órdenes, de todos modos las variables se usan en muchos otros casos, para darle órden al código, para no hacer lineas muy largas, imaginate si el string fuera largo y le tenés que sumar todo el codigo del document.querySelector.... + el string largo, esa línea no quedaría muy bien.
Con el tiempo te acostumbrarás a evaluar cuando te conviene utilizarlas, también las utilizarás mucho con algo llamado desestructuración, pero para e caso que indicas, creo que es el ejemplo más útil.